# Setup hangs with SECREPAIR: Hash Value for the file in MSI log

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have setup created with InstallShield 2015 Basic MSI project.
While installing the setup before installing the files the setup hangs for minutes and even more and in the MSI log file I get these kind of lines.

```
  MSI (s) (38!98) [15:58:41:394]: SECREPAIR: Hash Value for the file:program files\AAA\BBB\hwlib\S7IO\IOBG\IOBG17547.XML is: dXJdIksL5KIA2clSOFHHLMzqgxrtSxCj1B9WpZEe7MA=
```

I‘m not sure there is a connection to Microsoft KB2918614, KB3000988 and KB3008627 since in my case setup just hang but doesn’t fail.

I tried several workarounds to solve it like :
Uninstall these updates and update the product code under
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer\SecureRepairWhitelist] but it doesn't help in all cases..

1. Is there a settings in InstallShield I can use to avoid this problem ?
2. If there is a connection to the 3 Microsoft updates above do Microsoft intend to release another fix for these issues ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it is related to KB3072630. I the files are located e.g. on DVD-Drive then the hash generation takes a long time but it finally works.

InstallShield blames Microsoft.

I have a support incident pending at Microsoft Support.

Comment: Have you got any answer about this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you don't buy premier support you will never get a (useful) answer from Microsoft anymore, sad.